# Fgets and sscanf not waiting for input C

Tags: c, fgets, scanf

Originally I was using scanf, but I was running into the newline char getting stuck in the stdin. Everything I have read was saying to switch to fgets and use sscanf instead. With that, I decided to switch to that...but that still is not working. Below you will find my code. My question is, what am I doing wrong with my fgets and sscanf that is causing it to not wait for the user input?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct f_in{
    char outline;
    int lines;
    int rows;
    int num_args;
} F_IN;

typedef struct args_in {
    char in_string[20];
    int t_format;
} ARGS_IN;

void printInterface(char argQs[5][50], char argChar);

int main(int argv, char** argc){
    char defaultQuestions[5][50] = { { "1) What char for border?" }
            , { "2) Add question" }
            , { "3) Remove Question" }
            , { "4) Print last answers" }
    , { "5) Exit" } };
    int commandEntry, exitFlag;
    char borderChar = '*', addQ[50],userInp[1];

    exitFlag = 1;

    while (exitFlag){
            printInterface(defaultQuestions, borderChar);

            printf("Enter the integer value for the command you wish to select:  ");
            fgets(userInp, sizeof(userInp),stdin);
            sscanf(userInp,"%d", &commandEntry);
            printf("\nYou selected: %s\n", defaultQuestions[commandEntry - 1]);

            userInp[0] = 0;

            if (commandEntry == 1){
                    printf("Please enter the character you wish to be the border:  ");
                    fgets(userInp,sizeof(userInp),stdin);
                    sscanf(userInp,"%c",&borderChar);
            }
            else if (commandEntry == 2){
                    printf("What question would you like to add? (only enter 50 char max)\n");
                    fgets(addQ, 50, stdin);
                    printf("This was your question: %s", addQ);
            }
            else if (commandEntry == 5){
                    printf("Goodbye!\n");
                    exitFlag = 0;
            }
    }
    return 0;
}

void printInterface(char argQs[5][50], char argChar){
    int i, j;
    int lineCnt = 13;
    int borderLen = 75;

    for (i = 0; i<100; i++){
            printf("\n");
    }

    for (i = 0; i<lineCnt; i++){

            if (i == 0 || i == lineCnt - 1){
            for (j = 0; j<borderLen; j++){
                            printf("%c", argChar);
                    }
                    printf("\n");
            }

            else if (i >= 3 && i <= 10){
                    printf("%c    %s", argChar, argQs[i - 3]);
                    for (j = 0; j < ((borderLen - strlen(argQs[i - 3]))-6); j++){
                            printf(" ");
                    }
                    printf("%c\n", argChar);
            }

            else{
                    for (j = 0; j<borderLen; j++){
                            if (j == 0){
                                    printf("%c", argChar);
                            }
                            else if (j == (borderLen - 1)){
                                    printf("%c\n", argChar);
                            }
                            else{

                    for (j = 0; j<borderLen; j++){
                            if (j == 0){
                                    printf("%c", argChar);
                            }
                            else if (j == (borderLen - 1)){
                                    printf("%c\n", argChar);
                            }
                            else{                
                                    printf(" ");
                            }
                    }
            }        
    }                  

    for (i = 0; i<10; i++){ 
            printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly is not working ? What is the input ? What is the expected output ? Modify your question and make that clear.

Comment: What is happening is that it is not waiting for the user input on the first question asked, and immediately looping through again and repeating, ending in an infinite loop. What is expected is that it will wait for a user input to do one of the 5 default actions given.

Comment: That worked @user3121023, but what did that work vs just userInp[1]?

Comment: @user3121023, that makes sense...thanks for the assist!

Comment: The `printInterface` never ends because you reuse the same `i` variable for another `for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) `. It's at the end of the `printInterface` function. Thereare most likely other problems too.

Comment: Curious, @Dpry12, why did you code `userInp[1]` versus some other size like `userInp[30]` or `userInp[1000]`?

Comment: @chux, the reason I went that route was because at the time, I had figured since I only needed to accept the numbers 1-5 as my input, that a char array with one char would be sufficient. I totally forgot about the null terminator, hence the issue.

Comment: @Dpry12 Remember to even read 1 digit, would need size 3, `digit`, `'\n'`, `'\0'`.

Comment: do not use tabs for indenting.  Because every wordprocessor/editor has the tab stops/tab width set for personal preference.  I.E. only use spaces for indenting.   Suggest 4 spaces for each indent level as that is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts.

Comment: in `main()`, the `argv` is usually used to indicate a vector of pointers and the `argc` is usually used to indicate a counter that indicates the number of entries in the vector.

Comment: never access beyond `argv[0]` (using normal parameter naming) without first checking the `argc` counter to assure that the desired command line parameters actually exist.  When not going to use any of the parameters passed to `main()`, use the signature `int main( void )`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line.  2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers.  'magic numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 5, 50  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: this line: `fgets(userInp, sizeof(userInp),stdin);` is actually saying to input 0 characters, because `fgets()` always appends a NUL character to the end of the input field data and since the input field is only 1 character long all that will result in the input field `userInp` is a NUL character.

Comment: the code blocks, that begin with statements like: `if (commandEntry == 1){` would be much better consolidated into the case statements of a `switch()` statement. and their should be a final test (the default statement) that prints a message to the user about invalid input

Comment: @user3629249, thanks for the help! Making the changes to switch as we speak, and the other changes as well

Comment: strongly suggest clearing the screen, not by printing a bunch of newlines, but rather by using the terminal control escape sequences.  as outlined on this page: <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code>   Note: there is no need to print trailing spaces when outputting a line to the terminal (in fact, it is a bad idea.)  It would be much better to layout the whole 'menu' in the `defaultQuestions[]` array, then just print that array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"userInp[1] only allows enough memory to store the terminating '\0'"
 - user312023